# Android studio How to get int value (year, month, day) from CalendarView and use it to save in SQLite

Tags: java, android, calendar

my app is you can write your weight and connect that this date (day,month,year)

```
private void insertWeight(){
        String weightString = mWeightEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(weightString);

        final int mYear;
        final int mMonth;
        final int mDay;
```

That is getting text from editText (it is weight) here it's wors

```
        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                mYear = year;    
                 mMonth = month + 1;
                 mDay = dayOfMonth;
}
        });
```

that I try realise add information about date to data (SQLite)

```
WeightDbHelper mDbHelper = new WeightDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


        values.put(WeightContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT,weightString);
        values.put(WeightContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_DAY, mDay );
        values.put(WeightContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_MONTH, mMonth );
        values.put(WeightContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_YEAR, mYear );
```

here puting to the data base

problem is

```
@Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                mYear = year;    
                 mMonth = month + 1;
                 mDay = dayOfMonth;
}
        });
```

how to set mYear, mMonth, mDay Int number?
how i can use this have already been recognised value?
it's not only about calendar
how i can take a value of something, not for TaxteView, just for using in database?

Comment: Since SQLite hasn’t got a date data type, I would save a string in ISO 8601 format, like `2021-07-23`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can set them before functions. As I saw, you set them in a function and used them in another one . set them out of function and set their values in function.